# How to get the value from listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am writing a C# windows form application program. I have a code part like:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem + "\t" + "\t"  + textBox5.Text + "\t" + textBox4.Text + "\t" + textBox6.Text + "\n");
```

Here I want to take the value of `textBox6.Text` and I want to assign it to a double variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: but your code does something different you need to take textBox6.Text and use Parse or TryParse and assign to your variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use tryParse method

```
float val = 0;
float.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out val);
```